# **Help** with Upgrading FFTW.NET wrapper to .Net7/Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, fftw

I am attempting to upgrade the FFTW.NET wrapper to .NET 7 on my project using the [`FFTW.NET` by ArgusMagnus@github](https://github.com/ArgusMagnus/FFTW.NET). My project will not compile and is producing definition errors like:

> Error code: CS0117 'FftwInterop' does not contain a definition

[List of all errors]https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXpcQ.png

I believe the template file is not being compiled all the way through to create the '*.g.cs' file. Next, I am confused that the README says to change the names of the '.dll' files to "libfftw3-3-x86.dll" and "libfftw3-3-x64.dll" but after downloading the files there are 3 differently named '.dll' files? Then it says to put them into the application directory. What is the correct application directory?

[README](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj6nd.png)

[fftw-3.3.5-dll64 (win64 FFTW download)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ahu4.png)

Anything will help due to the lack of information over this issue...

Comment: `.lib` files are fonly or C/C++ linkers: they aren't directly executable and you can't use them from .NET: .NET needs `.dll` (or `.so` on Linux) files.

Comment: The `FFTW` NuGet package already targets `netstandard1.3` which means you can use it directly from a .NET 7+ project without any modifications - why are you wanting to rebuild it?

Comment: @Dai, I have been given the task to upgrade it by my job. From what you said I now see that the target is 1.3 and when I try to build it then I am given the same definition errors found in the picture..

Comment: The `FttwInterop.cs` file is generated by `FftwInterop.tt` - are you able to execute that T4 template in VS?

Comment: @Dia, from the information given in the **FFTW.NET.csproj** it says the **FftwInterop.tt** generates the **FftwInterop.g.cs** which is fails to do.

Comment: What errors or output do you get when you run T4? T4 will output error messages to the VS Error List as well as the Output pane (though you will need to change the Output pane's source).

Comment: I was able to run T4 on the `FftwInterop.tt` file and it successfully generated the `FftwInterop.g.cs` file. I've posted it to a GitHub gist here: https://gist.github.com/daiplusplus/cc0103ab0ef3cdebb7c07fd3ad85105b - you should be able to use it on your machine assuming you're also running 64-bit Windows and VS2019.

Comment: I've forked the repo and was able to upgrade the solution to .NET 5 without any trouble - and I've included a pregenerated `FftwInterop.cs` file in case you can't run T4 yourself: https://github.com/daiplusplus/FFTW.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe the template file is not being compiled all the way through to create the '*.g.cs' file.

Correct. That is the problem. The `.csproj` file for `FFTW.NET.csproj` does not currently run T4 (`TextTemplatingFileGenerator`) on-build: instead you have to manually run T4 via Visual Studio (right-click the `FftwInterop.tt` file and choose "Run custom tool" to generate the `FftwInterop.g.cs`.

The T4 file doesn't have any dependenencies: it's just a (glorified) self-contained macro-expansion that generates all those `DllImport` methods from a simple list of exported functions hardcoded in the T4 file (so I'm surprised the `FftwInterop.g.cs` file is excluded from source-control via `gitignore` as there's no reason *not* to include it, not least for the benefit of users without T4 in their build environment)

FWIW, I ported the https://github.com/ArgusMagnus/FFTW.NET project from .NET Standard 1.3 to .NET 5 and posted it to my GitHub fork here: https://github.com/daiplusplus/FFTW.NET which builds just fine in VS2019 (as of commit [12e4d3dce)](https://github.com/daiplusplus/FFTW.NET/commit/12e4d3dce548b47a7242b309354a0173731682e5).

> Next, I am confused that the README says to change the names of the '.dll' files to "libfftw3-3-x86.dll" and "libfftw3-3-x64.dll" but after downloading the files there are 3 differently named '.dll' files?

- I downloaded the `.dll` files from this page: http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

  - 32-bit: https://fftw.org/pub/fftw/fftw-3.3.5-dll32.zip
  - 64-bit: https://fftw.org/pub/fftw/fftw-3.3.5-dll64.zip
- Each `.zip` file contains 3 different builds of `libfftw3{type}-3.dll`, where `{type}` is either empty, `f`, or `l` - these 3 builds correspond to the "single/long/long-double" floating-point types.

  - The FFTW.NET library only seems to support the single-precision build (i.e. `libfftw3-3.dll`) so copy `fftw-3.3.5-dll32.zip\libfftw3-3.dll` **into the same directory as the `FFTW.NET.csproj` file** and rename it to `libfftw3-3-x86.dll` - do the same for `fftw-3.3.5-dll64.zip\libfftw3-3.dll` but rename that to `libfftw3-3-x64.dll`.

Like so:

[image]

> Then it says to put them into the application directory. What is the correct application directory?

Ignore that instruction; instead you'll want those `.dll` files to be included in the `.csproj` output, so do this:

- First, you need to include those `.dll` files in the `.csproj` file as Content, configured to copy-if-newer.

  - The `.dll` files will appear in Solution Explorer automatically once they're moved into the same directory as the `.csproj`, but they'll appear as "Build action: None" - you need to change that to "Content" and "Copy if newer", like so:

[image]

---

Then run the `TestAppNet5` project and it should *just work*:

[image]